# Solve the system of equations....!

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Can you please help me solve this system of equations (frankly I have no idea, it's the first equation of this type that I solve, so please, write only a hint):

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x-\arctan y=y-\arctan x \\ 
x^2-xy+4y^2=4
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality we may suppose that $x\ge y$. But if $x>y$, what is the sign of $(\arctan y-\arctan x)$ ? conclude that $x=y$ and finish the job.

Comment: But $x=y$ won't satisfy the second equation...

Comment: @Paul Safier: Sure? $x=y=1$ is a solution. $x=y$ must not "satisfy", it must be substituted into the second equation.

Comment: $x=y=1$ is **the only** solution, according to Omran.

Comment: Agreed. I suppose $x=y=-1$ might also be a solution if that's an accepted portion of the domain...